# Custom View subclass lose references

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-custom-view

I'm trying something like this

```
public class CustomViewSubclass extends HorizontalScrollView{

private LinearLayout layout;

public CustomViewSubclass(Context context) {
    this(context,null,0);
}

public CustomViewSubclass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context,attr,0);
}

public CustomViewSubclass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    layout = new LinearLayout(context);
}

// This is called from the `Activity`
public void startAsyncTask() { // code }

// This method is called in the `onPostExecute()` of an `AsyncTask` subclass
public void doSomething(Context context) {
    ImageView image = ImageView(context);

    layout.addView(image); // NullPointerException here, layout seems to be null
}
```

but it seems that `layout` on `doSomething()` is null. How is that even possible? I'm initializing it on the constructor... and I never re-initialize it again;

I'm adding my custom view via `XML`

```
<com.mypackage.CustomViewSubclass
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

Comment: try instantiating it onCreate() instead of the constructor

Comment: Can you post the stack-trace?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it, it was an stupid mistake made by me:

I used `super()` on the 3 methods, instead of using `this()`.

```
public CustomViewSubclass(Context context) {
    super(context,null,0);
}
public CustomViewSubclass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context,attr,0);
}
public CustomViewSubclass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    layout = new LinearLayout(context);
}
```

Solution:

```
public CustomViewSubclass(Context context) {
    this(context,null,0);
}
public CustomViewSubclass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context,attr,0);
}
public CustomViewSubclass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    layout = new LinearLayout(context);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `layout` be `null` if constructors `CustomViewSubClass(Context)` and `CustomViewSubClass(Context, AttributSet)`are called? If your problem is indeed fixed now, I suggest you look elsewhere in your code, since changing `this` to `super` most probably did not fix the problem.